# Show correct number in excel cell

Tags: c#, excel

I have the following command for the part numbers in excel file:

```
range.NumberFormat = "#,#";
```

But when the cell is zero zeros are not shown.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use `#,0` as your number format. From the [Excel Documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx), `#` means a digit, however do not show it if it is insignificant. Look at the section "Guidelines for using decimal places, spaces, colors, and conditions" for more information.